# Python Time Complexity of a small programm

Tags: python, time, time-complexity, computer-science, complexity-theory

I want to understand how to calculate the time complexity of the next algorithm. Basically, it is just a random number generator function that takes one single parameter *size* then, generates a list of random numbers while the length of the lists is different than the size parameter.

I am using `random.randrange` and `datetime`.

I am trying to understand how could I calculate the approx. time it will take to run instead of running it. **what would be the actual math with these parameters.**

I did some test with inputs: 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000.
Here are my results in a nice table:

| Input | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.000016 |
| 10 | 0.000022 |
| 100 | 0.000081 |
| 1000 | 0.000690 |
| 10000 | 0.007082 |
| 100000 | 0.068690 |
| 1000000 | still going on while I write this |

From what I understand the time complexity grows linear with N, but how could I do the math to have an approx time without computing this.

Here's the code:

```
def randomRegisteredVisits(size):
    randomNumbersList = []
    while (len(randomNumbersList) != size):
        randomNumbersList.append(randrange(0, size))
    return randomNumbersList

start_time = datetime.now()
miTestofRandom = randomRegisteredVisits(1000000)
end_time = datetime.now()
print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))
```

Comment: "still going on while I write this" seems surprising given the rest of the table. I would think that it should still be less than a second (it is less than a second on my machine).

Comment: Are you asking how you can interpolate a straight line through the data points you have measured? Or how you can do [Cross-multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication) in the simplest case?

Comment: I tried multiplying 1,000,000 times the amount of time for 100,000 and then dividing it by 100,000 and the result is 6.869 but at least in my computer it won't happen at that time

Comment: Ok, finally had a chance to try it on my computer. It took almost a second to run it for an input of 1,000,000 and 10 secs for it to run on an input of 10,000,000.

Answer (score 3):

Time complexity is `O(n)`, so it is linear.

It's linear as there is a single loop that loops for the entire range. If there was a loop inside loop then the time complexity would be `O(n*n)`, or `O(n^2)`